# Spark java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on using map

Tags: apache-spark

I am writing spark code and getting this error :
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException and a null-pointer exception on using map for joins. Any clues?

Comment: Please add a tag of language also, like whether your code is in Scala, Java, or Python? and add a code snippet to understand it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you got a dependency issue kindly check your dependency list once again for **com.fasterxml.jackson.core**

it must be like this in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope this helps, but it would be nicer you put your code snippet or exactly your error code.